# Multi keyfields DBLookupCombobox

Tags: delphi

I've a database with two tables: the first is named "Customers" and the second is named "Labels".

In Customers table I've this fields:

- Customer prefix (CHAR 1)
- Customer id (CHAR 6)
- Customer name (VARCHAR 50)

In Labels table I've this fields:

- Label id (AUTOINCREMENT FIELD)
- Label description (VARCHAR 50)
- Customer prefix (CHAR 1)
- Customer id (CHAR 6)
- Customer name (Lookup field)

In the first table the primary key is made by "Customer prefix" - "Customer id". The same fields are the foreign key in the second table.

In a Delphi form I've placed a TDBLookupCombobox in order to display the name of customer and I've set the **listsource** to Customers table and the **datasource** to Labels table, but I've to use to fields for setting **Keyfield**: *Customer prefix* and *Customer id*.
It seems there is no way to put two fields name in the KeyField of the DBLookupCombobox.

There is a way to use e multi fields key, like my example, with DBLookupCombobox?

Comment: have you tried 'field1;field2'?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use a TBLookupCombobox for a Lookupfield using multiple Keyfields, 
as a consequence of this even the use of the editor within a DBGrid will fail.
If you take a look into DBCtrls.pas you will find that in TDBLookupControl.UpdateListfields 
FKeyfield (TField) is extracted
`FKeyField := GetFieldProperty(DataSet, Self, FKeyFieldName);`
Since FKeyfield is a single field this will fail for a Lookupfield. 
The same will happen for the Masterfield(TField) in UpdateDataFields:
`FMasterField := GetFieldProperty(FDataLink.DataSet, Self, FDataField.KeyFields)`